# How to move LWJGL's window after it has been created?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I tried calling `Display.setLocation`, but it doesn't seem to work if the display has already been created.

Here's an example to demonstrate. I want the window to move up and down in response to the keyboard. When I run it, it prints "moving up/down", but the window doesn't move.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(640, 480));
    Display.create();

    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
      if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)) {
        System.out.println("moving up");
        Display.setLocation(Display.getX(), Display.getY() - 1);
      }
      if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN)) {
        System.out.println("moving down");
        Display.setLocation(Display.getX(), Display.getY() + 1);
      }
      Display.update();
      Display.sync(60);
    }
  }
}
```

I can get it to work by destroying and recreating the display with each `setLocation`, but I want to move the window in small increments, so it's not a practical solution.

I'm using LWJGL 2.9.1 on OSX.

(I also [posted](http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php/topic,5278.0.html) on LWJGL's forum. I'll be checking both sites.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this functionality just hasn't been implemented in the OSX port (although an older version, 2.8.5, did have it). I posted a [bug report](http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php/topic,5279.0.html).